# Many-to-many relationship between 3 tables in Django

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have the following models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    project_users = models.ManyToManyField('Users.UserAccount', related_name='project_users', blank=True)
    ....

class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    ....

class Discipline(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=27, choices=discipline_choices)
```

The DB table for `project_users` looks like this:

```
*--------*----------------*---------------------*
|   ID   |   project_id   |   user_account_id   |
*--------*----------------*---------------------*
```

I want to have an extra relationship in `project_users` field/table with the `Discipline` model. Is that possible in Django? I have been looking at [intermediary-manytomany relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) in Django, but that's not exactly what I want. In my application, there are a set amount of disciplines, and what I'm trying to achieve is to give each user multiple disciplines in a single project. So something like this:

```
*--------*----------------*---------------------*-------------------*
|   ID   |   project_id   |   user_account_id   |   discipline_id   |
*--------*----------------*---------------------*-------------------*
```

Is this possible?

Comment: have tried adding `disciplines = models.ForeignKey(Discipline, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` to `UserAccount`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a mode that refers to the three models, that is in fact what a `ManyToManyField` does behind the curtains: creating a model in between.

```
class UserProjectDiscipline(models.Model):
    user_account = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    discipline = models.ForeignKey(
        Discipline,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

You can now access the `UserProjectDiscipline`s of a `UserAccount`, `Project` and/or `Discipline` with `myuser.userprojectdiscipline_set.all()`, `myproject.userprojectdiscipline_set.all()` and `mydiscipline.userprojectdiscipline_set.all()`.

Furthermore you can define `ManyToManyField`s that span over this table, such that it is easy to obtain the related `Project`s of a `Discipline`, etc. with:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Users.UserAccount',
        through='UserProjectDiscipline',
        related_name='projects',
        blank=True
    )
    disciplines = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Discipline',
        through='UserProjectDiscipline',
        related_name='projects',
        blank=True
    )
    # …

class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    disciplines = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Discipline',
        through='UserProjectDiscipline',
        related_name='users',
        blank=True
    ) 
    # …
```

These will then make JOINs on the table of the `UserProjectDiscipline` to retrieve efficiently users for a given project, etc. If you need objects for the `UserProjectDiscipline`, you can still use for example `myproject.userprojectdiscipline_set.all()`.

If you thus want to give a user `myuser` three disciplines for a given project `myproject`, you add these with:

```
UserProjectDiscipline.objects.bulk_create([
    UserProjectDiscipline(user_account=myuser, project=my_project, discipline=mydiscipline1),
    UserProjectDiscipline(user_account=myuser, project=my_project, discipline=mydiscipline2),
    UserProjectDiscipline(user_account=myuser, project=my_project, discipline=mydiscipline3)
])
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you!