# Django Many to Many (through) with three tables and extra attributes

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have an already existing database with 3 tables: Person, Card, and Permission.
A user may have access to multiple cards, of which only some is owned by the person.
**How would I get all cards that the person has access to with the ownership status?**
Due to how the system should work, it's essential that the DB fetch is done in a single query. It's as if the usage of some magic values (such as objects.<table_name>_set....) is necessary to get this working?

Ideal target query (including the person table) would be:

```sql
SELECT card.id, card.text, permissions.owner
FROM person.id JOIN permissions ON person.id = permissions.person_id JOIN cards.id = permissions.card_id
WHERE person.id = <some person id>;
```

Example target result from the query fetching cards for user id=1:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "text": "some random text",
    "owner": false
  },
  {
    "id": 682,
    "text": "more random text",
    "owner": true
  }
]
```

I've also tried some other solutions in some other threads, but most of them either don't include the extra data from the through-table, or don't work as they seem to require an extra table (such as [Many-to-many relationship between 3 tables in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70566262/many-to-many-relationship-between-3-tables-in-django) which will throw an error "relation personcardpermissions does not exist" when attempting to construct the extra model).

Database table creation SQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE card (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    text VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE permissions (
    person_id INT NOT NULL,
    card_id INT NOT NULL,
    owner BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (card_id) REFERENCES card(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (person_id, card_id)
);
```

Currently used models:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'person'


class Card(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'card'


class Permissions(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, models.DO_NOTHING)
    card = models.ForeignKey(Card, models.DO_NOTHING)
    owner = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'permissions'
        unique_together = (('person', 'card'),)
```

Reading through Django documentation ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany ) regarding this exact problem, they don't seem to provide the solution to this, but rather just mention using multiple different queries using previous query results (at least how I understood the solution from them), which seems really expensive for such a simple query.

Comment: not sure how to approach the problem but perhaps it is solveable with serialisers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
from django.db.models import F

Card.objects.annotate(owner=F('permissions__owner')).filter(
    permissions__person_id=some_id
)
```

The `Card` objects from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.owner` that will specify if that person is indeed the owner.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Permission` instead of <s>`Permissions`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Your `Permissions` model acts as a junction table for a many-to-many relation between `Card` and `Person`. You can span a
> [**`ManyToManyField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField)
> on the `Card` model with:
>
> ```
> class Card(models.Model):
>     # …
>     persons = models.ManyToManyField(
>         Person,
>         through='Permissions'
>     )
> ```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you! For future reference if someone is having problems even with this solution: Check that the tables have correct ManyToManyField attributes and that the tables don't refer to each other as it seems doing that will sometimes break things in some cases/if done incorrectly, saying things like "Cannot resolve keyword 'permissions' into field."